# iOS MDM: Testing The Flow

Tags: ios, base64, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am developing an MDM solution. I have successfully installed profile on the device. Checked in the device on the server and got PushMagic and Token as PUT messages.

Now I am sending MDM payload before sending the command, but the device is not polling for the command as I can see in the IPCU console. How can I test if the payload is getting to the APNS server and if the APNS server is sending the push notification to the device? Is there any status code I get after sending the message to APNS? What is the correct length of the Token(I am getting 44 characters, and I am doubtful about the integrity of that).

Comment: How do you send the push notifications? What is the programming language you use?

Comment: We are using Python for constructing the packet and sending it to APNS server